# intallation gluon plugin eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mobile, gluon

I am trying to install gluon plugin on eclipse 2019 but I got this error and tried different ways but with no success. What is solution? Thank you

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Gluon Plug-in for Eclipse 2.6.0.v20180424-0818 (com.gluonhq.eclipse.feature.group 2.6.0.v20180424-0818)
  Missing requirement: Gluon Plug-in for Eclipse 2.6.0.v20180424-0818 (com.gluonhq.eclipse.plugin 2.6.0.v20180424-0818) requires 'osgi.bundle; com.google.guava [15.0.0,16.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Gluon Plug-in for Eclipse 2.6.0.v20180424-0818 (com.gluonhq.eclipse.feature.group 2.6.0.v20180424-0818)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.gluonhq.eclipse.plugin [2.6.0.v20180424-0818,2.6.0.v20180424-0818]
```

Comment: The install is trying to find a `com.google.guava` plug-in with version of at least 15.0.0 and less that 16.0.0. That plug-in isn't part of Eclipse. Do you have it installed? What version?

Answer (score 1):

The Gluon Plug-in for Eclipse v2.6.0 doesn't install in the current Eclipse, 2019-09.
That is documented at [this link](https://www.eclipse.org/setups/marketplace/?url=https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gluon-plugin).

---

Currently, the most recent version of Eclipse it runs on is 2018-09.
At least the gradle Task "run" will start your App on the Desktop.
(I used the "Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers" download package)

---

Before you get started, try getting a simple Demo App running in Android Studio.
Then you know Android Studio is configured correctly & set up for your phone.
How to get Android Studio installed & up-and-running is out-of-scope here.

---

Back to the Gluon Plug-in:
initially it won't deploy to Android with gradle task "androidInstall" as the Android SDK is missing "Android Support Repository" which is no longer available with current versions of Android Studio, but the "androidInstall" gradle task console-log outputs a DOS command-line to download it.
Something like
`C:/Users/.../Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "extras;android;m2repository"`

After running that I was able to install an App on my phone, albeit with some ?Charset? issues.

---

One more tip:
to get Javadoc for the Gluon Mobile classes, add the following to build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
eclipse {
    classpath {
        downloadJavadoc = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now the ONLY way that works installing this plugin (and efxclipse together with it) is by downloading it via their update site:

http://download.gluonhq.com/tools/eclipse/updates/1.0.0

Any marketplace aproaches will fail.

Anyways after you installed it it can happen that you still have to check for the correct Java version to use this plugin.